# WordPress plugin phpunit tests with dependencies

Tags: wordpress, unit-testing, woocommerce, phpunit, wp-cli

I suspect this would be a duplicate question or something with a very simple answer, but I've searched on every term I can come up with without any result.

It's really simple; **How can I unit test WordPress plugins that depends on other plugins?**

I'm currently working on a WooCommerce plugin which will contain a payment gateway, which has to extend the `WC_Payment_Gateway` included in the WooCommerce plugin. So I need WordPress to *load and activate* WooCommerce. I tried;

1. manually just including `/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php`. Gives me db errors as WooCommerce tables has not been created.
2. running `activate_plugin( '<woocommerce plugin path>' );` on the `"muplugins_loaded"` action. Gives same error as above.
3. Cloning WooCommerce dev. repo and including `test/bootstrap.php` in woocommerce. Gives me a PHP fatal error: `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/tmp/wordpress-tests-lib/includes/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/...`
4. Running `/plugins/woocommerce/tests/bin/install.sh`. Gives me `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare tests_add_filter() (previously declared in ...`
5. Combinations of the above

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I really don't want to drop unit tests but currently seems like the only option as I'm getting fatal b/c some classes in my plugin i.e. type hint the payment gateway which obviously forces the autoloader to get it.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

I just spent hours trying to figure this out, and got there eventually. Leaving this answer here for anyone else that's looking.

This guide explains the process quite well: https://wptheming.com/2016/01/unit-tests-for-woocommerce-extensions/

Basically you can copy the entire woocommerce test suite into your extension folder and make a few adjustments to the initialization in the bootstrap file, so that you load up woocommerce and your extension together.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating "Dependency substitution" (mock) classes in a special folder that is only registered to the autoloader in the test environment (not dev/prod to prevent collisions with the real classes).

I think it's a really ugly solution as the tests will pass even if the api that we depend on changes and breaks the application - breaks the whole point of doing unit tests imo. But you know.. All is fair in love and war lol

Comment: Quick and dirty you can include wp-load.php and with the right config vars you're golden. For simple testing, I would look into wp-cli to load activate plugins for a test scenario.